# Nested json path using variables in Postman Flow

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I have a scenario where I have some JSON ("lldp" in the image below), and I need to find a particular key and pull all of its values from within.  The particular key I need to pull is dynamic and is identified as the 'thisPort' variable.  All of this is shown in the screenshot below.

[image: A screenshot from Postman of a flow]

The lldp data basically looks like this.  Note how the ports are not within a list. Any given instance of the lldp data may contain anywhere between 1 - 48 ports.

```
lldp = {
   "port1": {"stuff":"things"},
   "port2": {"stuff":"things"},
   "port40": {"stuff":"things"}
}
```

I assumed I could do something like "lldp.thisPort" to access the keys and variables withing, however this produces useless errors and doesn't work.  In this case I passed it three different 'thisPort' variables from a list, so presumably its the same problem three times, and not three different problems.

[image: A screenshot from Postman of a blank error message]

'thisPort' does correctly come across to the Evaluate function as a string that should lead to a valid JSON path.  Eg, 'lldp.thisPort' does seem to translate to a valid path like 'lldp.port1', but Evaluate doesn't seem to agree and I get an error.

Using variables (or any other 'dynamic' way of working), how can you access the keys/values within some JSON as part of a postman flow, when the path to the thing you're trying to pull is dynamic?

Comment: You had better put this question to github. I don't see a way to resolve this var `thisPort` at runtime in Evaluate block.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$lookup(lldp, thisPort)` inside the Evaluate block to get the values inside the `thisPort` object.